# Matlab iterative polyfit

Tags: matlab

I have x and y data that has n number of points in each of the arrays.
I want to use polyfit on portions of the data.

I want to divide the data into a certain number of divisions(numDivisions).

My idea would be to do something along the lines of

```
n= size(x)%number of data points
        numDivisions = 4;%number of times to divide the data
        div = zeros(numDivisions,1)%number of points per division

        p = zeros(numDivisions,4);% second number is degree of polynomial+1
        S = zeros(numDivisions,1);
        mu = zeros(numDivisions,1);
        E = zeros(numDivisions,1);

        for i = 1:numDivisions
            div(i) = round(n(1,1)*i/numDivisions) %assign markers for divisions of points
        end

        for i = 1:size(div)
            if i == 1
                start = 1;
                endpoint = div(i);
                 [p(i), S(i), mu(i)] = polyfit(x(start:endpoint), y(start:endpoint), 3);
            else
             [p(i), S(i), mu(i)] = polyfit(x(div(i-1):div(i)), y(div(i-1):div(i)), 3);
            end

        end
```

The goal would be to have an array of p values from the polyfits.

However, when I run it I get this error:

*In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B
and I must be the same.
Error in (line 33)
                 [p(i), S(i), mu(i)] =
                 polyfit(x(start:endpoint),
                 y(start:endpoint), 3);*

Comment: what's iterative here exactly?  if `x` and `y` are vectors you can reshape them and use polyfit once on them

Comment: I want to use polyfit many times on portions of the data.  Instead of just one polyfit for the whole data set. Imagine having a set of points from 1-10 and then doing polyfit for each section 1-3, 3-5, 5-7, and 7-10.  But you can specify how many times you want to divide it up

Comment: Your approach looks like it should be OK, what's your question?

Comment: As daniel said, it is not really clear about the question. Yoor approach  does not seem to bad, so it is a bit complicated to figure out your problem. However, is it the fit that is important or is what you really want to do interpolation? It may be a stupid question from my side, but please do not feel offended.

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot about the question. lol.  I edited it to include that at the end.